# AWS and Ruby Stack - Error appears on elastic beanstalk deployment

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Ruby Stack configured with AWS Elastic Beanstalk. Last week, all my deployments were ok, but since I tried to change my MySQL RDS DB to use UTF-8, I got this problem each time I run an `eb deploy` :

```
INFO: Environment update is starting.                               
INFO: Deploying new version to instance(s).                           
ERROR: UnicodeEncodeError :: 'ascii' codec can't encode character u'\u2018' in position 90: ordinal not in range(128)
```

When I check on the AWS EB interface, I got this error message :

```
[Instance: i-2a4575cc] Command failed on instance. Return code: 1 Output: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/tmp/backup/10_bundle_install.sh’: No such file or directory. Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/post/05_revert_bundle_install_local.sh failed. For more detail, check /var/log/eb-activity.log using console or EB CLI.
```

Finally, I checked inside the /var/log/eb-activity.log as mentionned above, and the last lines are the following  :

```
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.079Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployEnactHook] : Completed activity. Result:
  Successfully execute hooks in directory /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/enact.
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.079Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Starting activity...
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.079Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/05_revert_bundle_install_local.sh] : Starting activity...
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.088Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/05_revert_bundle_install_local.sh] : Activity execution failed, because: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/tmp/backup/10_bundle_install.sh’: No such file or directory (ElasticBeanstalk::ExternalInvocationError)
caused by: cp: cannot stat ‘/var/tmp/backup/10_bundle_install.sh’: No such file or directory (Executor::NonZeroExitStatus)

[2015-06-16T09:03:39.088Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook/05_revert_bundle_install_local.sh] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.088Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1/AppDeployPostHook] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.088Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy/AppDeployStage1] : Activity failed.
[2015-06-16T09:03:39.088Z] INFO  [23525] - [CMD-AppDeploy] : Completed activity. Result:
  Command CMD-AppDeploy failed.
```

The problem seems to come from the `cp` command requested in the 05_revert_bundle_install_local.sh script :

```
cp -a /var/tmp/backup/10_bundle_install.sh /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/10_bundle_install.sh
```

The /var/tmp/backup/10_bundle_install.sh doesn't exist.

Do you know what could have happened ? And how can I solve it to avoid the error message and make clean deployments ?

Thank you !

Comment: do you have any ebextensions in place?

Comment: No I don't. It's a default ruby stack generated from EB : 64bit Amazon Linux 2015.03 v1.3.1 running Ruby 1.9.3

Comment: did you see [this](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=554473)?

Comment: Thanks ! Deleting the sh file did work perfectly !!

Comment: great, i'll post it as the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look [here](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=554473).

Apparently when installing the default sample app, beanstalk also installs this file and "forgets" to delete it. So the solution is simply to delete it manually.